# Use Python and Pandas to split data in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

I have the following data from a CFD simulation:

```
  Average value for X = 0.5080000265E-0003 to 0.2489200234E-0001          
  Z = -.3141592741E+0001     
  Time = 0.7000032425E+0001     
       Y             P_g     
  0.1511904760E-0002  0.2565604063E+0006
  0.4535714164E-0002  0.2565349844E+0006
  0.7559523918E-0002  0.2565098906E+0006
  0.1058333274E-0001  0.2564848125E+0006
  0.1360714249E-0001  0.2564597656E+0006
  0.1663095318E-0001  0.2564346563E+0006
  0.1965476200E-0001  0.2564095625E+0006
         ...                 ...
         ...                 ...
  0.1259419441E+0001  0.2549983125E+0006
  0.1262443304E+0001  0.2549983125E+0006
  0.1265467167E+0001  0.2549983125E+0006
  0.1268491030E+0001  0.2549982656E+0006
  Time = 0.7010014057E+0001     
       Y             P_g     
  0.1511904760E-0002  0.2565604063E+0006
  0.4535714164E-0002  0.2565349844E+0006
  0.7559523918E-0002  0.2565098906E+0006
  0.1058333274E-0001  0.2564848125E+0006
         ...                 ...
         ...                 ...
  0.1259419441E+0001  0.2549983125E+0006
  0.1262443304E+0001  0.2549983125E+0006
  0.1265467167E+0001  0.2549983125E+0006
  0.1268491030E+0001  0.2549982656E+0006
  Time = 0.7020006657E+0001     
       Y             P_g     
  0.1511904760E-0002  0.2565604063E+0006
  0.1058333274E-0001  0.2564848125E+0006
         ...                 ...
```

As you can see from the above example, the data is split into several vertical sections by the time step header labeled `Time`. In each section, `Y` does not change but `P_g` does change. To plot the data, I need the `P_g` in each section to be listed in the next column. For example, this is how I need to recreate the data:

```
      Y                0.7000032425E+1     0.7020006657E+1       ...
  0.1511904760E-0002  0.2565604063E+0006  0.2549982656E+0006  ...  
  0.4535714164E-0002  0.2565349844E+0006  0.2549982656E+0006  ...
  0.7559523918E-0002  0.2565098906E+0006  0.2549982656E+0006  ...
  0.1058333274E-0001  0.2564848125E+0006  0.2549982656E+0006  ...
  0.1360714249E-0001  0.2564597656E+0006  0.2549982656E+0006  ...
```

Using Pandas, I can read the data from the text file and create a new data frame with the `Y` values as the index (rows) and the `Time` values as the columns:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in data from text file
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# data frame from text file contents, skip first 4 rows, separate by variable
# white space, no header
df = pd.read_table('ROP_s_SD.dat', skiprows=4, sep='\s*', header=None)

# Time data
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# data frame of the rows that contain the Time string
dftime = df.loc[df.ix[:,0].str.contains('Time')]

t = dftime[2].tolist()  # time list
idx = dftime.index      # index of rows containing Time string

# Y data
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# grab values for y to create index for new data frame
ido = idx[0]+2      # index of first y value
idf = idx[1]        # index of last y value
y = []              # empty list to store y values

for i in range(ido, idf):   # iterate through first section of y values
    v = df.ix[i, 0]         # get y value from data frame
    y.append(float(v))      # add y value to y list

# New data frame
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

# empty data frame with y as index and t as columns
dfnew = pd.DataFrame(None, index=y, columns=t)
print('dfnew is \n', dfnew.head())
```

The head of the empty data frame, `dfnew.head()` looks like the following:

```
          7.000032 7.010014 7.020007 7.030043 7.040020 7.050035 7.060043  
0.001512      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
0.004536      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
0.007560      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
0.010583      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
0.013607      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   

         7.070004 7.080036 7.090022   ...    7.650011 7.660032 7.670026
0.001512      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN   
0.004536      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN   
0.007560      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN   
0.010583      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN   
0.013607      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN   

         7.680044 7.690029 7.700008 7.710012 7.720014 7.730019 7.740026  
0.001512      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
0.004536      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
0.007560      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
0.010583      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
0.013607      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  

[5 rows x 75 columns]
```

The `NaN` in each column should contain the `P_g` values from that particular `Time` section. How can I add the `P_g` values from each section to their respective column?

The text file that I am reading can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/id47otggh1niogp/ROP_s_SD.dat?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've already done most of the hard work ... the following few lines will finish unraveling your DataFrame:

```
# Add one more element to idx for correct indexing on the last column
idx = list(idx)
idx.append(len(df))

# Loop over the idx locations to fill the columns
for i in range(len(dfnew.columns)):
    dfnew.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[idx[i]+2:idx[i+1], 1].values
```

The head of `dfnew` is now something like this for the first 3 columns:

```
                    7.000032            7.010014            7.020007
0.001512  0.2565604063E+0006  0.2565604063E+0006  0.2565604063E+0006   
0.004536  0.2565349844E+0006  0.2565349844E+0006  0.2565349844E+0006   
0.007560  0.2565098906E+0006  0.2565098906E+0006  0.2565098906E+0006   
0.010583  0.2564848125E+0006  0.2564848125E+0006  0.2564848125E+0006   
0.013607  0.2564597656E+0006  0.2564597656E+0006  0.2564597656E+0006
```

You have a lot of elements, so probably the best way to view the data is in 2D:

```
data = dfnew.astype(float).values
extent = [float(dfnew.columns[0]),
          float(dfnew.columns[-1]),
          float(dfnew.index[0]),
          float(dfnew.index[-1])]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(data, extent=extent, origin='lower')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Y')
```

BTW, it looks like all the values for P_g at each time in your example file are the same anyway ...

Comment: This works great! Thanks. If you have time, an example of plotting each row as a line would be helpful. The x-axis should be time, t, while the y-axis should be pressure, P_g.

Comment: You really want 420 separate lines?  That's probably not the best way to look at that...

Comment: @Gavin I added some plotting code.  420 individual lines is going to be nasty, so I did it in 2D.

Comment: Yeah, when I first plotted the data, I just picked a few of the rows. I didn't know about `imshow` but I guess I can do the same thing using `contourf`. Again, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First, perhaps you could consider how you can reduce this to a 2d spreadsheet. What columns should go into each row? I suggest each row should contain `Time`, `Y` and `P_g`. Perhaps that can inform your strategy for handling your funky input format.

Second, for what `Y` value(s) are you trying to plot `P_g` v.s. `Time`? Your data appears to have 3 variables--you'll need to reduce to 2 dimensions in order to make a 2d plot. Do you want to plot the the mean of `P_g` for a particular `Time` value? Or do you want a 3d plot, where you plot `Y` v.s. `P_g` for each `Time` value? Assuming you adopt the row/col structure I suggested above, any of these can be easily done with pandas. Check out pandas `groupby` feature. [Here's more detail on that](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

EDIT: you've clarified both my questions. Try this:

```
import pandas, sys, numpy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    from StringIO import StringIO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    from io import StringIO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

# main dataframe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Time','Y','P_g'])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

text = open('ROP_s_SD.dat','r').read()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
chunks = text.split("Time = ")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
# ignore first chunk                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
chunks = chunks[1:]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
for chunk in chunks:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    time_str, rest_str = chunk.split('\n',1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    time = float(time_str)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    chunk_df = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(rest_str), sep=r'\s*', index_col=False)                                                                                                                                                                                         
    chunk_df['Time'] = time                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    # add new content to main dataframe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    df = df.append(chunk_df)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# you should now have a DataFrame with columns 'Time','Y','P_g'                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
assert sorted(df.columns) == ['P_g', 'Time', 'Y']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

# iterate over unique values of time                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
times = sorted(list(set(df['Time'])))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
assert len(times) == len(chunks)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
for i,time in enumerate(times):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    chunk_data = df[df['Time'] == time]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    # plot or do whatever you'd like with each segment                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    means = numpy.mean(chunk_data)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    stds = numpy.std(chunk_data)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    print 'Data for time %d (%0.4f): ' %(i, time)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    print means, stds
```

Comment: The x-axis would be `Time` and the y-axis is `P_g`. Each plot would be for a particular `Y` value.

Comment: In that case, I think my suggestion works. Find a way to get your data so that each row has `Time`, `Y` and `P_g`. Then you can do the following: 1. get unique values of the `Y` column, and 2. for each unique value of `Y`, select the appropriate subset of data and plot `Time` v.s. `P_g`

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do which is why I asked the question. I just don't know how to do it in Python.

Comment: Gotcha. I updated my answer to include some code which I think does what you want

Comment: Please read my question again, I added more code and better examples of what I'm trying to accomplish. Hope it helps.